# Suitable way to access SQL database from Web Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, dataset

I'm writing a webserver in C# to access a SQL database.  Currently just using SQL Server Express that comes with Visual Studio, but I need the flexibility to go to other SQL implementations in the future.  (e.g. MySQL)

I'm looking at the Data Access Layer, and trying to figure out the best way to do it.  There seem to be a lot of options around.

- DataSet - I don't know much about this one - I added a simple DataSet
  to my project, using the IDE, and it seemed to add a lot of incomprehensible
  auto-generated code, and I couldn't follow how to use it, except to retrieve the entire table, and then parse it myself.
- Linq to SQL - Not keen on this, due to "SQL-Server only" implementation.
- Linq to DataSet - Use Linq queries to retrieve a DataSet.
- Direct SQL - SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc

I'm familiar with SQL and comfortable writing my own SQL commands.  This method seems OK, to me, but with more modern methods available these days, am I completely nuts to build my own DAL interface classes and write SQL code to fill them?

Is querying a Dataset any easier or more flexible than querying in SQL?
Do I have to create a different dataset for every different query?  Or does the dataset load the whole table, and query that?

I am also concerned about the flexibility of DataSets in fitting with different or changing data below the Dataset.  If I start adding and removing columns to the tables, will that muck up the DataSet, and/or break my existing code the uses the DataSet?

I'm a bit old school, and believe in keeping everything simple.  Should I persist and learn how to use DataSet, or start diving straight into creating my own interface classes, and building SQL queries to fill them?

Comment: I would urge you to research entity frame work.

Comment: Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

Comment: Anything but the simplest DAL tends to degenerate into a treacherous morass (especially Entity Framework.) Have a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), it's what Stack Overflow uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is definitely the way to go, as suggested by the comments on my original question.  Entity framework v6 is installed through NuGet.  Once I got my head around setting up the Entity Framework, it was very easy to use, and allowed my business layer to use linq queries directly on each table.  The lazy loading feature looks very useful for using the foreign keys to easily jump from table to table, although I don't use this much in my code.

EF created all the data interface classes automatically, so I didn't have to do any of this.  As my database is a little 'fluid' during development, EF also makes it easy to propagate database changes through the code and automatically updates the data interface classes that represent the tables.

Answer (score 0):

For your concern about **Dataset**, well, it's more efficient for you to make your query for you to fill your DataSet for you not to have issues on your data whenever someone edit your data in your database. This also answers your question of "will that muck up the DataSet?", well since you have queries for your dataset, it will no longer muck up your dataset because you're manipulating your data from the back-end(database) and just retrieving/passing values through your code. And also another YES you MUST start diving straight into creating your own interface classes for object oriented approach which is commonly used nowadays.
Word of advice, whenever you're trying to use `SqlCommand`, it's better to have a stored procedure for this than to have a plain text(Query string) to have secure your data during Data Manipulation.